# Is it possible to create a custom Claim with JSON as value and not JSON string?

Tags: c#, json, jwt

i'm trying to create a custom JWT claim which it's value is a JSON.

When reading the JWT payload (JSON), i need the authorization claim to be added to it.

in the following example the authorization claim should have a JSON value (without quotes)

```
ClaimsIdentity claims = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
 new Claim(authorization, **json**),
 new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Aud,audience),
 new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub,user.ID.ToString()),
});
```

is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you store a deserialised version of Json in the claim (as an object) and then when reading it serialise it back to json?

Comment: What is a "JSON Value"? What kind of object model do you store it in?

Comment: i need to read the JWtoken and be able to 'use' its payload as JSON. go through the keys and values. now i'm getting the authorization claim as one single string.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can convert your JSON to string and add to to the claim. when you need it you can convert it back to JSON